# Passing data out

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, web-controls

I'm currently having a bit of a nightmare with a foreach loop. In a nutshell, what I am trying to do is split a string and then filter this data based on the string. I then need to bind the said data to a control of filter it further down the line. So far, I have the following code

```
 if (Session["Contract"] != null)
        {
            string[] contract = Session["Contract"].ToString().Split(',');
            foreach (string i in contract)
            {
                if (i.ToString() != "")
                {
                  data = data.Where(x => x.Term.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(i.ToString().Trim().ToUpper()));
                }
            }
        }

        LV_Jobs.DataSource = data;
        LV_Jobs.DataBind();
```

Now when looping through, the filtering works fine, but once you are finished with one item, the data variable is cleared? Obviously I need to pass "data" back out of the foreach loop. Can anyone point me in the direction of how to do this???

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here? What is `data`? What is its type? Does it have a value prior to this code? What is your expected output? Can you describe what are you trying to do in plain english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting `data` every time the loop iterates.  Try this (depending on what `data` is)

```
        var filteredData = new List<string>();
        if (Session["Contract"] != null)
        {
            filteredData = Session["Contract"].ToString().Split(',').Join(
                                data, 
                               i => i.ToString().Trim().ToUpper(), 
                               x => x.Term.Trim().ToUpper(),
                               (i, x) => x);
        }

        LV_Jobs.DataSource = filteredData;
        LV_Jobs.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply collect the needed data out in a list of results or any other data structure declared outside of the for/foreach scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is not cleared. Instead, in the last iteration of the `foreach` where `i.ToString() != ""` your `Where()` condition is *not true*. So `data` becomes an empty list.

You can `break` out of the `foreach` when you found what you were looking for.